# Beamer background image centered

Tags: beamer, graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, backgrounds

I'm trying to use an image as a background for Beamer presentation according to [this](http://mprnotes.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/changing-background-image-of-latex-beamer/) post.  However, I do not want the image spanning the entire background. Thus, I'm doing something like:

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{% \centering
\hspace{4.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{image.jpeg}
}
```

The `\hspace` command works, but `\vspace` does not work. Basically, I'm trying to get the image to be at the center of the page. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can box the image and then use `\vfil` and `\hfil` to center it:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
  \vbox to \paperheight{\vfil\hbox to \paperwidth{\hfil\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{name}\hfil}\vfil}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The line `\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}` was used to make my example compilable for everyone (replacing the image for a black rectangle); do *not* use that line in your actual document.

You can also use a `\parbox` with width and height equal to `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`, resp., and center vertically with the optional argument, and horizontally using `\centering`:

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
  \parbox[c][\paperheight][c]{\paperwidth}{\centering\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{name}}
}
```