# JPEGs in custom beamer theme

Tags: beamer

I have a few JPEGS that I need to place in a beamer theme. They are

- Cover Image - cover.jpg: 1st slide
- Header - header.jpg: 2nd slide only
- Footer - footer.jpg: 2nd slide to end

The Cover Image goes on the first slide, the header and footer appear on the title slide (after the footer), and the footer on every subsequent slide.

I've included an example:[image: example slide]

I have the footer as a jpeg, and I would like it show on every slide.

So far I've just arranged these in paint and saved a blank slide, and then used \usebackgroundtemplate:

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{frontslide.jpg}}
```

however, this has distorted the images unacceptably.

I've created a beamer theme as below:

Outer:
\mode

```
% Frame title
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{texsx}[1][]
{
\vskip1cm%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.2cm]{frametitle} 

  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\mode<all>
```

Inner:

```
\mode<presentation>

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\begin{tikzpicture}\node[opacity=.9]
{\includegraphics [width=\paperwidth]{slide.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

% Title page
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{cdt}[1][]
{ begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] \begin{pgfonlayer}{background} \node      at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]  {frontslide.jpg}}; \end{pgfonlayer} 
\end{tikzpicture}}

\mode<all>
```

Colour:

```
\mode<presentation>

% Settings
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white}

\mode<all>
```

The theme.sty:

```
\mode<presentation>

% Requirement
\RequirePackage{tikz}

% Settings
\useinnertheme{cdt}
\useoutertheme{cdt}
\usecolortheme{cdt}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]  

\mode<all>
```

How do I place these jpegs directly?

Comment: Did you try to add `keepaspectratio` option for `\includegraphics`?

Comment: @Ignasi no - I've placed them in another image that's the size of a slide, and used that as the background for the slide. Could I use \usebackgroundtemplate to set headers and footers?

Comment: Could you provide image showing what do you want?

Comment: @Ignasi Included example of the whole slide - I'd like to use just the footer.jpg and place it on all slides.

Answer (score 1):

If

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usebackgroundtemplate{
  \vbox to \paperheight{\vfil\hbox to \paperwidth{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Mi title}
Some text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

is what you want, please give some credit to Gonzalo for his answer to [Beamer background image centered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26458/beamer-background-image-centered).