# Centering a picture in the background of beamer

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

How to make the figure logo centered in the background, its a circle

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=table]{beamer}
 \usepackage{tikz}
     \newsavebox\mybox
    \savebox\mybox{% \setstretch{1.0}
        \tikz[opacity=0.1]\node[align=center]{%
       
            \includegraphics[width=7cm]{logo} \\
           };
    }
     \usebackgroundtemplate{
    \usebox\mybox}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 
 \end{frame}
 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look on this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/how-to-insert-a-background-image-in-a-beamer-frame, it may helps

Comment: I think it's the same question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26459/1952

Comment: Yes it is the same and I closed the question since its a duplicate